# Count overall cell index for grouped UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, math

I'm trying to create an index count for every cell in a grouped UITableView so I can store the cell values at correct positions in an array but I can't work out the math needed for it:

The index runs as follows, and my count needs to be:

```
indexPath.section = 0   
  indexPath.row = 0     cellIndex = 0
  indexPath.row = 1     cellIndex = 1
  indexPath.row = 2     cellIndex = 2
  indexPath.row = 3     cellIndex = 3
  indexPath.row = 4     cellIndex = 4

indexPath.section = 1
  indexPath.row = 0     cellIndex = 5
  indexPath.row = 1     cellIndex = 6
  indexPath.row = 2     cellIndex = 7
  indexPath.row = 3     cellIndex = 8
```

This is my equation so far but it's not working correctly:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger cellIndex = numberOfSections * indexPath.section + indexPath.row;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what your purpose for doing this is, but I suspect that what you're trying to do is not the way to go. Why do you think you need this calculated cellIndex?

Comment: I have a uitextfield inside each of the cells and I'm storing the value of these in an array as they are edited so they remain as the uitableview scrolls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a simple way to achieve this:

```
//Number of cells before this
int cellsBefore = 0;
for(int i = indexPath.section - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    cellsBefore += [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}
//Calculate cellIndex count
NSInteger cellIndex = cellsBefore + indexPath.row;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change `numberOfSections * indexPath.section` to `numberOfCellsPerSection * indexPath.section`. According to your comment of the answer, you can store the uitextfield value to the corresponding entity of the cell instead of using an array.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it's definitely the number of cells per section that needs to be calculated, however it gets more complex because each section has a different number of cells so I'll have to find this value. I can't store the uitextfield value with the cell because the cells are destroyed and recreated as you scroll

Comment: Do u have a data entity for every cell? If yes, just use the data entity for storing, otherwise use a `NSDictionary` to store it. The key of the dictionary can be `@"sectionIndex,cellIndex"`, and the value is the text field value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [TLIndexPathTools](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools). The `TLIndexPathDataModel` class can automatically organize items into sections and there are numerous convenience APIs to simplify view controller code. For example, you would get the total number of items like this:

```
self.indexPathController.items.count;
```

There are several sample projects demonstrating different use cases. The [JSON sample project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/JSON/JSON/JSONTableViewController.m) demonstrates organizing JSON data into sections using a `sectionNameKeyPath` property similar to how `NSFetchedResultsController` works (except that items don't need to be pre-sorted by section with TLIndexPathTools). It is also possible to explicitly create sections, including empty ones, by creating `TLIndexPathSectionInfo` instances. See the [Section Info sample project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Section%20Info/Section%20Info/SectionInfoTableViewController.m).

Comment: I added a total row count header to the "Section Info" example.